# What's the correct Schema.org type for a dentist service?

Tags: schema.org

I'd like to know what is the correct Schema.org Type for a dentist service like

- Orthodontics
- Pedodontics
- Dental bleaching
- Oral hygiene and prophylaxis

and many more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**`Dentist`**](http://schema.org/Dentist) is for the business and the location (because it’s a more specific [`LocalBusiness`](http://schema.org/LocalBusiness), which has [`Organization`](http://schema.org/Organization) *and* [`Place`](http://schema.org/Place) as parents).

[**`Service`**](http://schema.org/Service) for services provided by the `Dentist` (via the [`provider`](http://schema.org/provider) property).

[Health/medical](http://schema.org/docs/meddocs.html) concepts might be relevant, too (e.g., [`MedicalProcedure`](http://schema.org/MedicalProcedure)), but they can’t really be connected to `Dentist`/`Service`. Note that the health types [will likely become an extension](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/492).